vscode automatically adds space after typing closing bracket
I found a phenomenon in my vscode:
When I type a left bracket { , and then a right bracket } , vscode seems to automatically add spaces in between for me. I have tried disabling all plug-ins and it still seems to have this effect. Can anyone help turn off this automatic behavior?
After my testing, it seems that objects and types will not have such an effect.
it's wired!
I try to disabled all plugins but get no effect. So I think it may be a build-in function?

add more details like which file extension. Auto formatting is based on language and language is based on extension. Like in my case both in .py and .cpp that is not happening. Usually these are auto formatters that format the file and make these adjustments
